# Android: Heavy DB operations with progress dialog

Tags: java, android, database

I have used to [following](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction%28%29) idiom on the `doInBackground` method of an AsyncTask for quick inserts into the DB:

```
    mDatabase.beginTransaction();
    try {
            //... do DB stuff

            mDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
            mDatabase.endTransaction();
    }
```

However, if I use this idiom, my progress dialog (placed in the `onPreExecute` method) is not displayed. On the other hand, if I replace the above code with regular mDatabase.execSQL() statements, the progress dialog does get displayed but inserts become very slow. Is there any way I can have the best of both worlds (i.e., progress dialog and fast insertions). Thanks!

Note: beginTransaction run in EXCLUSIVE mode (I don't get what that means tbh). Is this the cause?

Comment: Is your progress dialog shown in PreExecute() and hidden in PostExecute() ?

Comment: yep. it works fine if i use SQLiteDatabase.execSQL for insertions instead of the above idiom. however, these are painfully slow so im pretty much stuck with using the above idiom...

Comment: Have you tried keeping a reference to the ProgressDialog outside the AsyncTask to show/hide it yourself ? That's what I would try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Apparently, it was what I was doing before doInBackground which was the problem. I had defined the following:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgD = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "", "Wait", true);
        ih = new InsertHelper(mDatabase, "dictionary");
        wordColumn = ih.getColumnIndex("word");
    }
```

If I move the code below ProgressDialog.show into doInBackground before the beginTransaction idiom, then the dialog gets shown. I still don't get why this happens but there it is. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Show your dialog before starting the `AsyncTask` (e.g., via [`showDialog()`](http://goo.gl/QdW75)).

Comment: thanks. but this isn't working either. the progress dialog only gets displayed AFTER all the inserts happen. do you think this happens because of the beginTransaction idiom? if i use regular sql statements to insert, everything works well..

Comment: If you were putting this in your onCreate, it was likely locked *before* onCreate finished by the beginTransaction() call.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and I think I can explain what is happening (in my case).

beginTransaction() locks your database, so if the context you put into your database is your activity, it will also lock your activity from finishing your onCreate (therefore, not allowing your progressdialog to show).

The simple fix to my program was to put the thread to sleep for a few hundred ms, then locking the database/activity via beginTransaction() once the progressdialog has initialized.