# AsyncTask TimeOut Situation Solution

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am using `asynctask` to execute some task.
I also want to implement to complete in 60 sec else give a time out exception message.

So I am using the `AsyncTask.get(time,timeFormat);`

Example:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try {
                        validateConnection.execute().get(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                        stopConnTask();
                        invalidCrediantialsError(Utilities.TIMED_OUT_ERROR);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }catch(CancellationException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    };
                }
            }).start();
```

It works fine as `AsyncTask`. Get blocks in `UI` thread so I am running it in separate `thread`.
Is this approach right or I have to think of something else.

Comment: asynctask is asyncrhonous it will not block the ui thread unless you are calling `get` and not `execute`

Comment: but i am calling both  validateConnection.execute().get(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  still it blocks

Comment: remove `get` and it should run fine

Comment: also asynctask must be invoked on the ui thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public final Result get ()

Added in API level 3
Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

Returns
The computed result.
Throws
CancellationException   If the computation was cancelled.
ExecutionException  If the computation threw an exception.
InterruptedException    If the current thread was interrupted while waiting.
```

Calling `get()` will not make asynctask asunchronous. `get()` waits for the result blocking the ui thread. Remove `get()` and use execute like for example `new 
TheTask().execute()`.

Also asynctask must be invoked on the ui thread

Comment: It run fine , i also do not want to use get, actually i want my asynctask to complete before 60 sec else give a time out message. Thats why i used get.

Comment: Actually i am usign asynctask to check a connection string  for connecting to database, weather the connection string is returning  connection or it is wrong

Comment: what is that you are doing in asynctask a http request?

Comment: No buddy, using to check connection string for database

Comment: to check conenction what do you do?. You check n/w availability or internet connectivity.

Comment: No database connection string like . jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433/Blog", "user", "password")

Answer (score 1):

An AsyncTask is primarly intended for longer running tasks that would cause an ANR in the UI thread and report back its results to the user interface.

If your task runs up to 60 sconds, this means your activity should stay open the same time. Do you really want this? Or don't you need to apply any results to the UI?

In any case, I'd recommend to use a service having a thread inside. You could either start an intent from that service or send a broadcast for further processing by the user interface.

**p.s.** [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16912768/asynctasks-get-method-is-there-any-scenario-where-it-is-actually-the-best-op) gives some idea in which case `AsyncTask.get(...)` might make sense: basically said, only if your AsyncTask is doing some initialization that is a kind of fundament for the for the UI.

**p.p.s**: have you considered to specify a JDBC connection timeout? Check for instance [this site](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-jdbc-internals-and-timeout-configuration/) for more  details.

Comment: I am trying to check a mysql db connection string using the asynctask. If the string goes correct then the result may come with a sec. However user may enter all incorrect credentials, so overall i want the check should be till 60 sec else give time out exception

Comment: Any time the async task finishes or time out exception come  i need to open a dialogfragment for next step .

Comment: I want the task to finish with in 60 sec because usually db connections are fast and if a task is taking more then 60 sec there fore some thing is wrong in user credentials for connecting db.

Comment: @Suresh Bora: if you really need to block your whole UI until you are sure that the database connection is working, then `get(...)` might be a good choice. However, for achieving a stable network/database operation in various environments I'd rather stick to a service that tries to connect. May be including a kind of queue implementation.